# Let user pick directory of where a created text file is placed

Tags: vbscript

How do I take the user input and let that be the directory for a text file?

I tried putting quotes around the ("Inp.txt") but this doesn't read the actual user input.

```
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Inp= InputBox("Please Enter Desired Location of Log File:")
If Inp= "" Then  
    Set oTF = oFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Old Files.txt")
Else 
    Set oTF = oFSO.CreateTextFile(Inp.txt)
End If
```

I want to prompt the user for an input asking where they'd like to place their created text file; if left blank i would set it to a default location. I tried setting an inputbox prompt but when i use that as the text file location I receive an "Object Required" runtime error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//z0z2z1zt%28v%3dvs.85%29) a complete path from the directory and a file name:

```
Set oTF = oFSO.CreateTextFile(oFSO.BuildPath(Inp, "output.txt"))
```

I would recommend letting the users [browse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774065%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the folder, though.

```
Set app = CreateObject( "Shell.Application" )
Set d = app.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select Folder", 1, "C:\")
If d Is Nothing Then
    Inp = "C:\"
Else
    Inp = d.Self.Path
End If

Set oTF = oFSO.CreateTextFile(oFSO.BuildPath(Inp, "output.txt"))
```